# Counting Lines and displaying a struct arrays in C

Tags: c

This is what i have so far. I need to read the file day.txt, count the number of lines in the file

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h" 

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 

struct earthquake_t{ 
    float lat;
float lng;
float dep;
float mag;
};
FILE* fid;
int main(void)
{
double lat,lng dep,mag;
double userminlat,userminlng,usermaxlat,usermaxlng,minlat,minlng,maxlat,maxlng,i, ch,line;
struct earthquake_t *earthquake;

fid=fopen("day.txt","r");

while (!feof(fid))
{        /*Need help counting lines*/
    count = fscanf(fid," %lf %lf %lf\n",&lng,&lat,&dep,&mag);
/* count tell you how many of the % fields were matched,
 and you need to make sure all three were found to avoid blank lines*/

    if (count ==3)
    {
        line ++;
    }
}

fseek(fid,1,SEEK_SET);
print("%d\n",sizeof(struct earthquake_t));        
earthquake = (struct earthquake_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct earthquake_t)*line);

for (i=0;i<line;i++)
{        
    fscanf("fid,%lf %lf %lf\n",&lng,&lati,&elevi)
    earthquake[i].lat=lat;
    earthquake[i].lng=lng;
    earthquake[i].dep=dep;
    earthquake[i].mag=mag;


    /*Setting the min and max values for latitude and longatidue*/
    if(earthquake[i].lng >maxlng) 
    {     
        maxlng = earthquake[i].lng;
    }
    if(earthquake[i].lng >minlng)
    {    
        minlng = earthquake[i].lng;
    }
    if(earthquake[i].lat >maxlat)
    {
        maxlat = earthquake[i].lat;
    }
    if(earthquake[i].lat >minlat)
    {
        minlat = earthquake[i].lat;
    }

}
```

Comment: good work... can you tell us what is the problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `fgets()` to get a whole line from the text file and put it into a string and use `sscanf()` to extract your values.

```
/* count tell you how many of the % fields were matched,
and you need to make sure all three were found to avoid blank lines*/
```

The [scanf man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) states in part:

**Return Value**

These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error.

You could check for `line[0] == '\n'` to avoid blank lines.

Hope that helps.